# Concatenate using an array formula to result in last name.firstname

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

We have a form that asks for the students first name and last name.  I am trying to using concatenate and an array formula to display "Lastname.Firstname".

I used:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE($B$52:$B,".",$B$52:$C))
```

but it displays all the last name, a period, then all the first names - looking like this `smithjohnsonjackson.johngeorgeharry`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

- perhaps try it like this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A), B:B&"."&A:A, ))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thank You user0, that formula works perfectly

Comment: @AnilBanatwala https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers